# Generated POJOs with hibernate reverse engineering - How to create POJOs containing other objects?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I'm using hibernate reverse engineering to generate my Java classes from a MySQL database.
I'm using Eclipse Juno with Hibernate Tools.
Everything's going fine but I'd like to take it a step further and I'm stuck.

Let's say the reverse engineering generated a class `Calls.java` and a class `Users.java`.

```
/**
 * Calls generated by hbm2java
 */
@Entity
@Table(name = "calls", catalog = "myDB")
public class Calls implements java.io.Serializable {

    private String id;
    private String name;
    private Date dateEntered;
    private String modifiedUserId;
    private String assignedUserId;
...
}

/**
 * Users generated by hbm2java
 */
@Entity
@Table(name = "users", catalog = "myDB")
public class Users implements java.io.Serializable {

    private String id;
    private String userName;
...
}
```

The properties `modifiedUserId` and `assignedUserId` from `Calls` are actually the `id`'s from a `Users` instance (in the db they are foreign keys).

When I set only one foreign key (let's say for `assignedUserId`), I get the following definition of Calls.java:

```
/**
 * Calls generated by hbm2java
 */
@Entity
@Table(name = "calls", catalog = "myDB")
public class Calls implements java.io.Serializable {

    private String id;
    private String name;
    private Date dateEntered;
    private String modifiedUserId;
    private Users users;
...
}
```

As you can see, I loose the name for `assignedUserId`.
However, if I define 2 foreign keys (for `assignedUserId` and `modifiedUserId`), the property that will be of type Users will be the first foreign key defined in the table (in my case, `modifiedUserId`).

```
/**
 * Calls generated by hbm2java
 */
@Entity
@Table(name = "calls", catalog = "myDB")
public class Calls implements java.io.Serializable {

    private String id;
    private String name;
    private Date dateEntered;
    private Users users;
    private String assignedUserId;
...
}
```

What I'd like to obtain in the generated class `Calls.java` is to have `modifiedUserId` and `assignedUserId` to be of type `Users` and not to be `String`:

```
/**
 * Calls generated by hbm2java
 */
@Entity
@Table(name = "calls", catalog = "myDB")
public class Calls implements java.io.Serializable {

    private String id;
    private String name;
    private Date dateEntered;
    private Users modifiedUserId;
    private Users assignedUserId;
...
}
```

Would anyone have any tip on how to do this? 
I've been checking a lot of tutorials on how to generate POJO's from a DB as well as the jboss documentation for the reverse engineering; but I cannot find a clue on how to include an object in a generated POJO class.

Thanks a lot for any help!
Kind regards,
BS_C3

Comment: How is your DB structure, do you have the proper foreign keys for assignedUserId and modifiedUserId?

Comment: Hi. Yes I have the proper foreign keys set. I've updated my post to add some details.

Comment: Use reverse-engineering only to get initial classes and then fix them manually.